# Calculate an integral with delta function

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

---

In order to calculate the integral
$$
f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\delta\Big(x-\sqrt{1\pm\sqrt{1-\beta^2\sin^2t}}\Big)\mathrm{d}t
$$
where $\beta\in(0,1]$. I am hunting for a better solution, which can handle the problem powerfully. Here below is my solution for case $-$.

> > Setting $u=\sin^2t$, then $\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u(1-u)}}\mathrm{d}u$. Therefore,
> >     $$
> > f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{1}\delta\Big(x-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\beta^2u}}\Big)\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u(1-u)}}\mathrm{d}u
> > $$
> >     By using of the integral property of [delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), we finally arrive at
> >     $$
> > f(x) = \frac{4x(1-x^2)}{\pi\sqrt(1-(1-x^2)^2)\sqrt(\beta^2-1+(1-x^2)^2)}.
> > $$
> >     Similarly, one can calculate the case for $+$.

Comment: Your approach is the right one; you have to do the transformation because otherwise if you just substitue for $\sin^2 t$  the delta function substitution is off by the derivative of $\sin^2 t$.  However, I don't get the same answer: Check your algebra.

Comment: @MarkFischler: Hi, thank you. I checked my answer again but failed to find out the error. Could you please tell me what's your answer?  Tks again.

Comment: @MarkFischler: I find that I havn't make some simplification in my above answer.